# How to display multiple links in a modal box in perl?

Tags: html, css, perl, modal-dialog

I am trying to display multiple links in a single modal box on `onclick` function like this

```
$cgi->img({ -src =>'/images/question.png',
            -width=>10,
            -border=>0,
            -height=>10,
            -alt=>'Redirect Link',
            -onClick=>"image_click()"
           }
          ),$cgi->div({-id="modal1",-class=>"modal"},$cgi->div({-class=>"modal2"},$cgi->span({-class=>"close",-onclick=>span_click()"},'&times;'),$cgi->p({},$links),),)
```

It's working fine when I want to display a single link but if I want to display multiple links in the same box.I wasn't able to get it.Instead I am getting the text of it. 
My links looks something like this

```
  my $links="'select a link',\$cgi->a({-href=>somelink},'LINK1'),\$cgi->a({-href=>somelink},'LINK2');
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

In this line:

```
my $links="'select a link',\$cgi->a({-href=>somelink},'LINK1'),\$cgi->a({-href=>somelink},'LINK2');
```

`$cgi->a(...)` is a method call, you have it in a double quoted string, but you can't interpolate method calls in a double quoted string.

Try something like this instead:

```
my @links = 'select a link', $cgi->a({-href=>somelink},'LINK1'), ...
```

Which creates an array of things rather than trying to put all the things in a string.  Then change

```
$cgi->p({}, $links)
```

to:

```
$cgi->p({}, @links)
```

I haven't tested this - sorry.

Just because you're using CGI doesn't mean you have to use the CGI methods for generating HTML.  I would strongly recommend looking at using a templating module like [Template::Toolkit](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Template-Toolkit/lib/Template/Tutorial/Web.pod), or a framework like [Mojolicious](https://metacpan.org/release/Mojolicious) which can be run from CGI and includes a templating system (and has next to no dependencies).